# Changes in the database affected hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that changes in hibernate entity will automatically sync with database if hibernate session is active and entity in persistent state. But I want it work in opposite direction: if something changes in database table it should automatically sync with hibernate entity and change its fields
Is it possible?

Comment: Nothing that would work automatically. You can only have external tools generate classes which are based on the tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. [JPA refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) should help you to manually do this.